# ResNet How to achieve accuracy as in the document?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I implement the ResNet for the cifar 10 in accordance with this document https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf
But my accuracy is significantly different from the accuracy obtained in the document
My - 86%
Pcs daughter - 94%
What's my mistake?

https://github.com/slavaglaps/ResNet_cifar10

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit too generic, my opinion is that the network is over fitting to the training data set, as you can see the training loss is quite low, but after the epoch 50 the validation loss is not improving anymore.

I didn't read the paper in deep so I don't know how did they solved the problem but increasing regularization might help. The following link will point you in the right direction http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/

below I copied the summary of the text:

> Summary
>
> To train a Neural Network:
>
> - Gradient check your implementation with a small batch of data and be aware of the pitfalls.
> - As a sanity check, make sure your initial loss is reasonable, and that you can achieve 100% training accuracy on a very small portion of
>     the data
> - During training, monitor the loss, the training/validation accuracy, and if you’re feeling fancier, the magnitude of updates in relation to
>     parameter values (it should be ~1e-3), and when dealing with ConvNets,
>     the first-layer weights.
> - The two recommended updates to use are either SGD+Nesterov Momentum or Adam.
> - Decay your learning rate over the period of the training. For example, halve the learning rate after a fixed number of epochs, or
>     whenever the validation accuracy tops off.
> - Search for good hyperparameters with random search (not grid search). Stage your search from coarse (wide hyperparameter ranges,
>     training only for 1-5 epochs), to fine (narrower rangers, training for
>     many more epochs)
> - Form model ensembles for extra performance

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the difference in data pre processing makes the difference in performance. He is using padding and random crops, which in essence increases the amount of training samples and decreases the generalization error. Also as the previous poster said you are missing regularization features, such as the weight decay.

You should take another look at the paper and make sure you implement everything like they did.

Comment: On which layers is it better to use regularization?